# Java Generics : Bounding without Inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

In java Generics, is there a way to tell that a certain type is not a subclass or super class of another class ? I mean we can use Upper and Lower bounding on some relationship hierarchy.
But how can we do it in the other way such that `<? isNotASubTypeOf A>`.

Comment: can you better clarify you question? Maybe some practical example would help.

Comment: such that...?? Common we're listening.

Comment: Why would you want to?  Unless your inheritance hierarchy goes ten deep - then you may want to use interfaces instead at that point.

Comment: This is a moronic thing to desire

Comment: I'll say it like this.. Sam has a video game and he lets everyone else  play it except for Henry or his children. If we have the above mentioned feature in generics, implementing this would be very easy...

Comment: Generics are not for arbitrary constraints. Generics are only for eliminating certain casts that it can prove is safe. If your restriction doesn't do that, then generics is not for it.

Answer (score 3):

so you want

```
<T !extends Foo>
```

nope.... can't do that

Answer (score 0):

Though this does not answer your question, though in such cases I think pattern Matching in Scala is extremely useful. You can he something like this.

```
typeVariable match {
case A => //do whatever
case B => //do whatever
case _ => //do whatever
```